# How can I find the cut vertices from this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

$G = (\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}, \{\{a,b\}, \{b,c\}, \{c,d\}, \{d,e\}, \{e,f\}\})$ implies the following are cut vertices:

a

b

c

d

e

f

Is each group of vertices in the list a strongly-connected-component?

Comment: "Strongly connectedness" is usually a feature of subsets of a directed graph, but what you have here is an undirected graph.

Comment: IS {} notation undirected?  So () is directed?

Comment: Also, is each {a,b} a connection?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Eric in the comments, strongly connected components refer to directed graphs, whereas you have given us an undirected path $P_5$.

Suppose you meant the directed edges $( a,b ) , ( b,c )$, etc. to be your edge set.  Then we would have a directed path, whose strongly connected components are the vertices themselves (we have no directed cycles, so this is trivial.

In fact, the individual vertices $\{ a \} , \{ b \},$ etc. will be the strongly connected components no matter what orientation we choose for your graph, since we cannot create any directed cycles.

So assuming that one of the above is what you meant, then your strongly connected components would consist of the individual vertices.

I hope that this helped.